# Ruby some array elements in nested .each block become nil

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want each array element to interact with each other array element. However, some elements in my code have an unexpected value of `nil`.

How do I avoid this undesired behaviour?

Here's the code to combine the elements: (it just prints the pairs)

```rb
def remove_sum_of_zero(arr)
  arr.each do |n|
    arr.each do |x|
      unless arr.index(n) == arr.index(x)
        puts "#{arr[n]} is being checked with #{arr[x]}"
      end
    end
  end
end

numArr = [3, 4, -7, 5, -6, 6]
remove_sum_of_zero(numArr)
```

output:

```
5 is being checked with -6
5 is being checked with
5 is being checked with 6
5 is being checked with 3
5 is being checked with
-6 is being checked with 5
-6 is being checked with
-6 is being checked with 6
-6 is being checked with 3
-6 is being checked with
is being checked with 5
is being checked with -6
is being checked with 6
is being checked with 3
is being checked with
6 is being checked with 5
6 is being checked with -6
6 is being checked with
6 is being checked with 3
6 is being checked with
3 is being checked with 5
3 is being checked with -6
3 is being checked with
3 is being checked with 6
3 is being checked with
is being checked with 5
is being checked with -6
is being checked with
is being checked with 6
is being checked with 3
```

I have tried using different arrays and each time different values become `nil`.

Comment: If you intend to actually remove zero sum pairs, keep in mind that you shouldn't mutate an array while traversing it.

Answer (score 4):

`each` yields the elements, not their indices, i.e. `n` becomes `3`, `4`, `-7`, `5` etc. Passing that value as an index via `arr[n]` doesn't make much sense.

If you're curious how [array indexes](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Array+Indexes) work in Ruby – negative indices count from the array's end with `-1` being the last element:

```
numArr = [ 3,  4, -7,  5, -6,  6]
#          0   1   2   3   4   5   6 ... ← positive indices (and 0)
# ... -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1         ← negative indices
```

If you need the element and its index, there's [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)  which yields both values at once:

```
def remove_sum_of_zero(arr)
  arr.each_with_index do |a, i|
    arr.each_with_index do |b, j|
      next if i == j

      puts "#{a} is being checked with #{b}"
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can utilize [`permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) which can yield all pairs: (i.e. same as above)

```
def remove_sum_of_zero(arr)
  arr.permutation(2) do |a, b|
    puts "#{a} is being checked with #{b}"
  end
end
```

Or, if comparing `a` to `b` is equivalent to comparing `b` to `a` (i.e. if order of elements is irrelevant), you might want [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) which omits those "duplicates":

```
def remove_sum_of_zero(arr)
  arr.combination(2) do |a, b|
    puts "#{a} is being checked with #{b}"
  end
end
```